# Post request with Content-Encoding: GZIP, DEFLATE possible?

Tags: java, gzip, backend, micronaut, content-encoding

I have a problem with my Micronaut backend and it's decoding.
I want to post content with following header and gzipped body content:

```
Content-Encoding: GZIP
```

but my Micronaut backend can't decode it. Is there a workaround, for example a HttpServerFilter? How can i solve the problem?

Kind Regards,
Christian

Comment: Are you also setting the "Content-Length" header?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Following headers are sent: 

`Accept: application/json, 
Content-Encoding: gzip, 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, 
Content-Length: 310, 
Host: localhost:8082, 
Connection: Keep-Alive, 
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_121), 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate`